# I want to make php form with 3 attempts

Tags: php

I want to make a simple game with php (guessing the number) and i have 3 attempts to guess the number.. how the page will refresh after every attempt ? and save attempt after refreshing ?

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <title>Guessing Number</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #ecb731;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <center>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <h1>Guessing Game</h1><br><br>
                <label>Enter the number  <input type="text" name="num">
                </label><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-
                primary" value="Check Number!">
            </form>
        </div>
     </center>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 

$attempt = 0 ;
$number = 5;

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )){
    $num = $_POST['num'];
}
while ($attempt < 3){
if ($num > $number){
    echo "The number is bigger than the actual number";
    exit;
}
if ($num < $number){
    echo "The number is smaller than the actual number";
    exit;
}
if ($num == $number){
    header ("location:sucess.php");
}

else if ($attempt > 3) {
    echo " you finished all allowed attempts";
    break;
}
    else
 $attempt++;
}
?>
```

in the page : sucess.php this code :
    Very Nice , You Success !

Comment: You need to post a code, and we will try to solve the problem with that code, have you tried anything?

Comment: did u see the code?

Comment: You can use Sessions to store data no?